# How to change the background color of a specific WooCommerce category?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors, elementor

I have Elementor + WooCommerce.
I have in my archive products page the following ->

All products; Category1 with its products; Category2 with its products.

Now, I want that in my archive products page, all the products related to Category2 have to have a blue background. Only the products related to Category2.

I can't find a way to do it, could you give me some help?

Comment: You must first share the looped code of the products.

Answer (score 2):

In WooCommerce category archive pages there is a body class set for it that you can use to target specific product category. There is 2 possible ways using:

• product category term ID,  *(let say that term Id is `53`)*:

```css
.tax-product_cat.term-53 .elementor-my-element{ background-color: #0080FF; }
```

• product category term slug,  *(let say that term slug is `category2` )*:

```css
.tax-product_cat.term-category2 .elementor-my-element{ background-color: #0080FF; }
```

where `.elementor-my-element` is the selector class of the element where you want a blue background (to be replaced by the correct real selector class of the html element).